# clicker game in java functionality

Tags: java, swing, timer, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to write a "ClickerGame" that the user need to click on a button as much as he can in 1 min. 
Can you help me to improve the functionality of this program? it's not really working.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class ClickerGame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    int i,j;
    JPanel panel;
    JFrame frame;
    JButton start;
    JButton stop;
    JButton click;
    JTextArea text;
    JLabel label;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ClickerGame a = new ClickerGame();
        a.go();
    }

    public void go(){
         frame = new JFrame();
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

         JPanel panel = new JPanel();

         click = new JButton("Click");
         click.addActionListener(new ClickListener());

         start=new JButton("Start");
         start.addActionListener(new StartListener());

         stop=new JButton("Stop");
         stop.addActionListener(new StopListener());
         panel.add(start);
         panel.add(click);
         panel.add(label);
         frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,panel);

         frame.setSize(500,500);
         frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    class ClickListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

            click.setText("Number of clicks: "+i);
            i++;
        }

        }

    Timer timer = new Timer(1000,new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            Date currentTime = new Date();
            label= new JLabel(currentTime.toString());


        }
    });

    class StartListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            timer.start();
        }
    }
    class StopListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            timer.stop();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you get an Error (Exception?) you should add the Exception to your question. Edit: If you don't get an Exception you should explain your Error/Problem

Comment: Sorry, i added the errors to the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
panel.add(label);
```

In this line.. label is not initialized. Please initialize it before using like this -

```
label = new JLabel("ABC");
```

Comment: I added it on the timer ,  where can i put it so it will show the current time?

Answer (score 1):

Your error is caused by trying to add `label` to the `panel`, as `label` is never initialised (`null`).

Remove: `panel.add(label);`

I'm not convinced the functionality of your game is as intended, but that's a separate question.

Comment: I added it on the timer ,  where can i put it so it will show the current time?

Comment: and the functionality is the main thing i wanted to know about, how can i improve it?